# python, loading multiple instances of something

Tags: python, json

I am making a creature simulator, at the end of the every creature, should dump a json form of their information to a single file. Then in the morning, the simulator should be able to pull all of the creatures information from that single file and reinstantiate them like they were before. 
So is there a way to have:

```
newDailyFile = path+day
with open(newDailyFile, "a") as file:
    for i in creatures:
        dump({'name':name, 'numbers':n, 'strings':s, 'x':x, 'y':y}, file, indent=4)
        #The only thing that is guaranteed to be unique is the name
```

then

```
with open("text") as file:
    result = load(file)
    for something in result:
        creature = Creature(result)
```

The issue is in the second part, I dont know how to read each creature individually. How can I do that?

Comment: `pickle` the class instances.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Unfortunatly I am required to use json. Good news is I found a solution, but thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change the way I was writing the strings and reading them back.

```
newDailyFile = path+day
with open(newDailyFile, "a") as file:
    for i in creatures:
        dump({'name':name, 'numbers':n, 'strings':s, 'x':x, 'y':y}, file) #removed indent so each one is online
        file.write("\n")#or else they will all be on the same line
```

then

```
with open(newDailyFile) as file:
    lines = file.readlines() #Gets each one line by line, then I can load them
    for i in lines:
        result = loads(i)
```